# On states and dimensions in Von Neumann algebras

Tags: operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

In an exercise, it is given that all the states satisfy normality. Can we prove the algebra to be finite dimensional? Maybe the premise means that it must be separable, and then I can show that it is finite dimensional?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your idea can work, as normality is not related to the norm-topology.

I also don't see an obvious way to prove the exercise directly from the material in the chapter (not saying it's not possible, just that I don't see it; the fact that $M_*=M^*$ might lead to something).

One way to prove the assertion is to show that every infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra $M$ has a non-normal state. For this, one shows that in any infinite-dimensional von Neumann algebra there is an increasing net $\{p_j\}$ of projections with $p_j\nearrow 1$ and $p_j\ne 1$ for all $j$. Then the subspace $P=\overline{\operatorname{span}}\{p_j:\ j\}$ does not contain $1$. By Hahn-Banach, there exists $\varphi\in M^*$ with $\varphi(p_j)=0$ for all $j$ and $\varphi(1)=1$.

The problem is that $\varphi$ might not be a state. But Theorem III.4.2.(ii) allows us to write any functional as a linear combination of states. So $\varphi$ is normal, but that's a contradiction. Thus $M$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. Second- I didn't quite understand the construction of the net. In what topology does it converge to 1? In order to contradict normality I suppose it should in the ultraweak topology. But then how isn't 1 contained in the closure P? The norm topology is smaller than the ultra weak and so the net must converge to 1 in this topology as well.      THANKS AGAIN!

Comment: Sorry, you asked about normality, I thought you knew what it meant. It is one of the most basic facts of von Neumann algebras that any bounded, totally ordered net of selfadjoints has a supremum, and said supremum is the sot (wot, etc) limit of the net. The net of projections is constructed a bit differently for each type (I$_\infty$, II$_1$, II$_\infty$, III); the I$_\infty$ case should be trivial to you. Finally, you got your topological facts wrong; the norm topology is "smaller", if you want; that means that not every ultraweak-convergent net is norm-convergent.